# Access return value from VBA Function in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, office-interop

I have the following code in VBA (which resides in an Excel 2007 Workbook):

```
Public Function Multiply(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
    Multiply = a * b
End Function
```

If I invoke Multiply from other VBA code, it returns the correct value.  However, when I call Multiply from C#:

```
var excel = new Application {Visible = true};
excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
var returned = excel.Run("Sheet1.Multiply", (Double) a, (Double) b);
```

... the multiplication takes place (I can verify this by adding tracing to the Multiply function in VBA) but the returned value isn't available in my C# code; `returned` is always `null`.

Could someone please tell me how to get at the return value of Multiply from my C# code?

Comment: I have been able to work around this by modifying Multiply() to set the value of a cell to the return value, and reading the value of that cell from C#.  Ugly but it works.

Comment: Any idea why it works from a module but not from the sheet?

Comment: None I'm afraid.  I actually haven't done any significant work on Microsoft stuff since 2011, so this is probably going to go un-answered unless someone else out there can help ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried moving your function to a regular module in Excel (not a sheet module)?

Comment: I created a new Module, moved the Function to that, and changed "Sheet1.Multiply" to "MyModule.Multiply".  Worked perfectly, thanks :-)  Just one question: was this an insight you gained through experience, or is this actually documented somewhere?  The information on MSDN etc. is pretty sparse for calling VBA via. interop.

Comment: @DuncanBayne `Sheet1` is an *object*, an *instance* of a `Worksheet` class. In order to call into members of a class, you need an instance - and the `Sheet1` instance only lives in the VBA runtime, .net doesn't see it. Standard modules are just that: procedural modules exposing executable code through public members; you don't need (you couldn't anyway) to *instantiate* it to call its members. That's why it works in `Module1` and not in `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example :

The test *spreadsheet.xlsm* has `Module1` containing:

```
Public Function test() As String
  test = "hello 1234"
End Function
```

With `objExcel` already set to the spreadsheet...

```
Dim result = objExcel.Run("Module1.test")
MsgBox(result)
```

... produces `hello 1234` in the pop-up message.

Because I had originally tested this with `? module1.test()` *(successfully)* in the VBA Immediate window, I was initially trying to get `objExcel.Run("Module1.test()")` to work - but I was getting an error: `Cannot run the macro .... The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.` - removing the brackets did the trick.

Answer (score -4):

Try modifying your Multiply function to be like the code below:

```
Public Function Multiply(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
    return a * b
End Function
```

Comment: That isn't even valid VBA. See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2007-HA010218996.aspx

Comment: You can't use the return keyword in VBA - you need to set the return value to the function name e.g. Multiply = a * b, which was in the original question.

Comment: This is VB.Net, not VBA.